# Why does new feature created not snap to existing feature vertices in ArcGIS 10?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, editing, arcgis-desktop, snapping

I have created a polygon feature earlier then I wanted to create points on the polygon vertices but it won't snap on top of the vertex.

I wanted to know the reason why it does not snap and is there any ways to convert the vertices into points instead of manually doing it?

Thanks

Comment: There is a bug in snapping.  I run into it regularly. I don't have a nim number but it should be logged with esri support.  It seems to most often present itself with agsonline basemap in the document. My workaround has been to copy the layers I want to edit and need for reference out to a new MXD with the view set to data frame view (not layout view). However this does not always work.

Comment: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/23795-Snapping-doesn-t-work!!  Still not an answer but it seems to be the same issue. I refuse to use classic.

Comment: Thanks Brad Nesom. I found the solution by deleting the spatial index then recalculate it in the feature class properties. It seems there were some errors with the spatial index that prevents the vertices to snap on the display.

Comment: That's good but can you now post that solution as an Answer (rather than just a Comment) so that you can then Accept it, please?

Comment: I was hoping that deleting and recreating spatial indexes would help, but it did _not_ work for me; still unable to snap to an added polygon layer using ArcGIS Engine.

Answer (score 1):

It should snap provided the **[Snapping environment](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m60000001s000000)** has been set up correctly via the Snapping toolbar.

Things to double check are:

1. Is **Use Snapping** checked on?
2. Is **Vertex Snapping** depressed (i.e. on)?
3. Are the polyline features you want to snap to the vertices of visible?
4. Is your **Snap Tolerance** something sensible like 10 pixels?

I notice that you have embedded a second question, and recommend that you post that separately.

Comment: That's good but can you now post that solution as an Answer (rather than just a Comment) so that you can then Accept it, please?